# Remove Html Element before it is rendered in page using javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working in very large project without Using any js Framework and Lib . I had a serious problem where I am looking for way to remove the HTML element before it is rendered in page. The code shown below is not actual problem but it helps me to find my actual solution . Please help me ?

code:-

```
 var element = document.createElement('div');
 element.innerHTML = 'This is Nirikshan Bhusal'
 element.remove()
 document.getElementById('root').appendChild(element);
```

I want logic something that above code shows.
I have 1 solution for this problem but this doesn't work for me

Codes That doesn't solve my problem :-

```
 var element = document.createElement('div');
 element.innerHTML = 'This is Nirikshan Bhusal';
 element.style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('root').appendChild(element);
 element.remove();
```

Please help me ?

Comment: If you want to `remove()`, why appending it?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean _hide_ instead of _remove_? Removing is the opposite of appending. Just don’t `remove`. If you want to hide it, simply leave that `element.style.display = 'none';` line there.

Comment: @Satpal but my real problem is similar to this .

Comment: Then why don't you ask about your *real problem*?

Comment: Dear @KooiInc because my problem is similar to this logic , I have already mentioned above

Comment: Elements will display unless the CSS tells them to hide. JS will only remove once the element is in the DOM. You always risk the element being displayed before you are able to remove it. Either hide the element be default or don't include it in the first place.

Comment: @JonasW stackoverflow dosn't allow me to post 20,000 lines of code

Comment: You are supposed to create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - emphasis on minimal. You can certainly give us an idea of the real problem you have. Just remove the line with `appendChild` then...?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with native elements. But you could easily monkey patch it:

```
Element.prototype.remove = (old => function() {
  this.dontAdd = true;
  old.call(this);
})(Element.prototype.remove);

Element.prototype.appendChild = (old => function(el) {
  if(!el.dontAdd) old.call(this, el);
})(Element.prototype.appendChild);
```

So now your first version works as expected. But this can cause side effects all over your code, so be careful with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the question described in the title.

Sometimes you want to remove an element that cannot be captured via CSS selector within the style sheet. For example you want to remove elements that have a specific inner text.
The problem is that using `element.remove()` will cause the element to show for an instance and then disappear (flicker)

The way I overcame this issue is by hiding the whole `<body>` using CSS and revealing it back using Javascript once the desired element is removed, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="us">
  <head>
    <title>My Cool Page</title>
    <style>
      body {
        visibility: hidden  /* <===== Starting from a hidden body tag */
      }
    </style>
   

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Listen to this event to make sure all DOM elements are loaded so you can access them
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

          // Select the element how ever you want, here I am selecting a span that contains a "world" text in it
          const xpathSelector = "//span[contains(text(),'world')]";
          const element = document.evaluate(xpathSelector, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
          if (element) {
            element.remove();
          }

          // **** reveal body again once you already removed the elements you want ****
          const body = document.evaluate("//body", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
          body.style.visibility = "visible";

        }
      });
    </script>

    
  </head>
  <body class="bla">
    <div id="root">
      <div class="container">
        <span>hello world i am gonna disappear before body is painted, and you are not gonna see me at all</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```